# how to limit the number of categories to be displayed in wordpress using custom template?

Tags: php, wordpress

My code in custom template is

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
'hide_empty'       => 0
) );

foreach ($categories as $cat) : ?>
<div class="fusion-one-third fusion-layout-column fusion-spacing-yes">

    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
        <h1 class="customp"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></h1>
    </a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It is displaying every category created but I want to display only 6 latest categories. No matter if these categories have any posts or not.

Comment: See the following: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/ this shows you what filters / values the array within get_categories accepts. I'm not sure if you can filter by most recent categories created though...

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any LIMIT option you can set with that function.

As an alternate you can slice it using PHP function:

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
'hide_empty'       => 0
) );

$number_of_categories = 6 // Whatever you want to 
$categories = array_slice($categories, 0, $number_of_categories, true);

foreach ($categories as $cat) : ?>
<div class="fusion-one-third fusion-layout-column fusion-spacing-yes">

    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
        <h1 class="customp"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></h1>
    </a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Give a try!!

Comment: It's working...  semicolon missing after 6... upvote from my side

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, I used counter and it worked perfectly.

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'hide_empty'       => 0,
    'parent'  => 0
) );
$limit=6;
$counter=0;
foreach ($categories as $cat) : 
if($counter<$limit){

    ?>
<div class="fusion-one-third fusion-layout-column fusion-spacing-yes">

    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
        <h1 class="customp"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></h1>
    </a>
</div>
<?php $counter++;
                }
 endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think in you can use [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) with the `offset` parameter to limit the number of categories, and `orderby` and `order` parameter to get the latest ones:

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', array(
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'offset' => 6,
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));
```